# c# Error when using .resx in form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio to create a Windows Forms application in C#.

In the form all texts are set without using resources, like so:

```
this.label1.Text = "Label text";
```

When I use the designer tool it seems like it extracts values to a .resx file it creates automatically, and turns the code above to:

```
this.label1.Text = resources.GetString("label1.Text");
```

It would be nice to have the resources in a separate file, however, when the .resx file exists the build fails with the following error:

> Error 1   The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. Δεν είναι δυνατή η εύρεση του καθορισμένου αρχείου από
>   το σύστημα. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that
>   the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task
>   contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

The non English part translates to "System could not find file".

The error remains even if no resources from the .resx file are used.

It only builds if I delete the .resx file.

What am I doing wrong and what could I try to fix it?

#### EDIT

I was trying to build for .net 3.5, changing to 4.5 the build error stops.

Comment: Your machine is broken, you need to get it fixed.  Rerunning the VS installer and choosing the Repair option is the obvious next step.

Comment: @HansPassant sadly this did not work. Could you please clarify what in my system you would expect to be broken so that I try fixing it?

Comment: "turn windows features on or off" in the start menu and ensure .net 3.5 is checked

Comment: @AlexK. There is an entry for .net 3.5.1 (not 3.5 if it makes a difference) and it was already checked.

Comment: Have you tried to create your resource file and replace 'this.label1.Text = "Label text";' with "this.label1.Text = YourResource.YourKey";'?